# Updating Mono object by another Mono object

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, reactive, spring-mono

Dears,
I'm a stuck with implementing a function (it is basically an update operation) that's capable of taking a Mono as a param and return an updated version of Mono where:

- the returned instance derives from a db query;
- the updated version of Mono contains fields picked by Mono.

This is the sample code (that works from providing directly the object, without using the Mono instance:

```
public Mono<CompanyDto> updateById(String id, CompanyDto companyDtoMono) {
    return getCompanyById(id).map(companyEntity -> {
        companyEntity.setDescription(companyDtoMono.getDescription());
        companyEntity.setName(companyDtoMono.getName());
        return companyEntity;
    }).flatMap(companyEntity2 -> reactiveNeo4JTemplate.save(companyEntity2)).map(companyEntity -> companyMapper.toDto(companyEntity));

}`
```

Question is: how can I change the code if the function signature would be

```
public Mono<CompanyDto> updateById(String id, Mono<CompanyDto> companyDtoMono)
```

PS:

```
getCompanyById(id)
```

returns a

```
Mono<CompanyEntity>
```

Thanks,
best

FB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many solutions for this problem but one of them is using Zip

```
    public Mono<CompanyDto>  updateById(String id, Mono<CompanyDto> companyDtoMono){
 return    Mono.zip(getCompanyById(id),companyDtoMono,(companyEntity, companyDto) -> {
        companyEntity.setDescription(companyDto.getDescription());
        companyEntity.setName(companyDto.getName());
        return companyEntity;
    })
         .flatMap(companyEntity2 -> reactiveNeo4JTemplate.save(companyEntity2))
         .map(companyEntity -> companyMapper.toDto(companyEntity));
}
```

Comment: Oh! There was so obvious :) What about other solutions?

Comment: you can use flatmap and inside flatmap continue with other stream like getCompanyById(id).flatmap(e-> companyDtoMono.map(m->{ here edit data and return result back}